# google chart prevent xaxis annotation overlap

Tags: annotations, google-visualization, overlap, linechart

I'm looking to make this line graph more readable by making one series annotation on top and the other series on the bottom. currently if they are close they are on the same line you can't hover over the other and can't read it. Does anybody know a way to do this?

would post image but site will not allow it so only posting whats important

```
var options = {
    title:'Availibility comparison '+labela+' and '+labelb,
    width: 1150,
    height: 600,
    backgroundColor:'white',
    annotation: {style: 'line'},
    vAxis: {
        minValue: 99.94,
        gridlines: {count: 20}
    },
    series: {
        0: {
            color: 'blue',
            pointSize: 2                                      
        },
        1: {
            color: 'purple',
            pointSize: 2
        }
    },
    chartArea: {
        width: 950
    },
    annotation: {
        1: {
            style: 'none'
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry, but there is no way to control the placement of the annotations.  You can file a feature request to add support for this [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list).

Comment: thanks, I did come across that comment while searching was hoping their was an update or a hack someone came up with, what about highcharts I haven't tried it yet but the demos look nice, I was thinking google could almost do the same and it is free

Comment: If you are feeling adventurous, you can manipulate the SVG/VML code to move the annotations, but there is no easy way to do so.

Comment: can get to some elements with jquery but,looks like have to change the attribute  and css values after the chart is rendered

Comment: I get same results with Hichcharts, but highcharts does give some addded features like saving to img or pdf and print